# Configuration to allow optional belongs_to association not working in rail 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

In rails 5, I could make `belongs_to` association optional using this setting:

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
```

but this does not appear to work in Rails 6. Is there a way to do this in Rail 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the new framework defaults file for Rails 5, it had the following

```
# config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb
# Require `belongs_to` associations by default. Previous versions had false.
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
```

So it appears that the option has been removed completely for `Rails 6`. So you will need to do it on a case by case basis by adding `optional: true`. In my case, in most cases, I ended rewriting the code so that the association was required.

Comment: the option still works for me in rails 6.1.4

Answer (score 2):

**The option still works in Rails 6**, but you need to make sure you set it after loading default config values, i.e.
`config.load_defaults 6.0`

The best place place would be towards the end of `config/application.rb`

```
    ...
    # Don't check for the existence of belongs_to records
    config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
  end
end
```